# Specifying Matrix Shape

Tags: matrix, maple

Is there a way I can specify that a matrix is hermitian before using the function Eigenvalues to find the eigenvalues for the matrix?

I have the following proc which creates a matrix that is the sum of another real matrix and it's transpose divided by two.

```
GOE := proc(N::integer) 
  local R, eigenSequence, i; 
  global H; 
  R := Matrix(N, N, Generate(distribution(Normal(0, 1)), makeproc = true));
  H := 1/2*R + 1/2*R^%T; 
  print(IsMatrixShape(H, Symmetric)); 
  return (eigenSequence := ([seq(Eigenvalues(H)[i], i = 1 .. N)])/(2*N)^0.5); end proc;
GOE(5);
                             false

    [-0.994570000000000 + 0. I, 0.468840000000000 + 0. I, 

      0.391240000000000 + 0. I, -0.0636860000000000 + 0. I, 

      -0.286700000000000 + 0. I]
```

Despite H being Hermitian, `IsMatrixShape(H, Symmetric)` returns `false`. Is there any way I can explicitly tell Maple that H is Hermitian?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the construction of `H` in a call to the `Matrix` command, giving the option,

```
shape=symmetric   (or hermitian)
```

The `Eigenvalues` command knows that the results in this case will be purely real.

I quote some names to make it safe, in the case that you have also assigned to the key words at a higher level.

You can save a Matrix-scalar multiplication by adding `R+R^%T` before dividing by 2.

For example,

```
GOE := proc(N::posint) 
  local R, i;
  global H;
  R := Statistics:-Sample(Normal(0, 1), [N,N]);
  H := Matrix((R + R^%T)/2, 'shape'=':-symmetric'); 
  print(IsMatrixShape(H, ':-symmetric')); 
  return [seq(LinearAlgebra:-Eigenvalues(H)/(2*N)^0.5)];
end proc:

GOE(5);

                          true

 [-0.6534952738123082, -0.48271907292646454, 

  -0.08120522250873016, 0.46015902976640316),

   0.9573556811378775]
```

Your code snippet omitted any loading of the `LinearAlgebra` and `RandomTools` packages, so doesn't run stand-alone as you have given it. It is better either to use the long form names in a procedure, or utilize the `uses` command within it, than it is to have the procedure's functionality rely on `with` being first called at the top-level.

If you Maple version is very old then the `seq` command usage I gave (direct on the `Eigenvalues` result Vector) may need adjusting.

For larger examples I believe that the `Statistics:-Sample` command may outperform your use of the `RandomTools` package (and it's simpler, IMO).

For example,

```
GOE := proc(N::posint) 
  local R, i;
  global H;
  uses LinearAlgebra, Statistics;
  R := Sample(Normal(0, 1), [N,N]);
  H := Matrix((R + R^%T)/2, 'shape'=':-symmetric'); 
  print(IsMatrixShape(H, ':-symmetric')); 
  return convert(Eigenvalues(H)/(2*N)^0.5, list);
end proc:
```

I'd also suggest that you have your procedure return `H` as well as the result, rather than write to a `global` which is clumsier if you're not operating at the top-level.

```
GOE := proc(N::posint) 
  local H, R, i;
  uses LinearAlgebra, Statistics;
  R := Sample(Normal(0, 1), [N,N]);
  H := Matrix((R + R^%T)/2, 'shape'=':-symmetric'); 
  print(IsMatrixShape(H, ':-symmetric')); 
  return H, convert(Eigenvalues(H)/(2*N)^0.5, list);
  end proc:

H,res := GOE(5):
res;
H;
```